# is it possible to connect amazon web service rds with amazon web service cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cognito

i am developing a android application using AWS's RDS and AWS Cognito service. so my question is there any way that i can connect the RDS with Cognito? please help.

Comment: DynamoDB can be a good alternative to RDS that you wanted to use, especially for use profile information. With it you can us the credentials from Cognito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two possible questions here so I'll answer them both.

1. If the question is, can I access RDS from a Cognito authed app:

RDS does not use AWS credentials for authentication, it uses database credentials. Cognito only vends credentials for AWS services, so you cannot use Cognito credentials to access an RDS database.

2. If the question is, can I link RDS to Cognito so I can query, manipulate or analyze your end users' datasets:

All access to users' datasets is done through Cognito.  There is no export or link feature that allows you to use RDS.