# Connect my iOS app to my EC2 Instance on AWS?

Tags: json, rest, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance set up on my AWS and I can easily connect using SSH through terminal. I have some jar files on my EC2 that I can run through this SSH connection. Now I would like to know:

How can I connect to my EC2 and run these same jar files from an iOS app that I am developing, and NOT use the SSH because that's not safe.

I looked into Apache web server, PHP, Amazon API, REST API, Dropwizard, endpoints, JSON, and a myriad of other things, and I am very confused. (I am a beginner still)

Please help!

Also - not sure if this is worth mentioning - I added port 80 and 443 on my EC2 security groups.

Comment: You should use an API based approach to achieve this. Here is a detailed example of doing this with spring(https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). It can output a jar and you can run it in EC2 as a service, and then call the API from the iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

There is an existing StackOverflow article that might help:

[Connect to an Amazon EC2 instance from an ios application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976150/connect-to-an-amazon-ec2-instance-from-an-ios-application)